# Selenium downloads tmp file instead of CSV file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, csv-file

When I download a CSV file from a [blob](http://qnimate.com/an-introduction-to-javascript-blobs-and-file-interface/) URL, the downloaded file always has a ".tmp" extension and wrong file name. When downloading the same file manually, the file extension and file name both are correct. Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Please share the code snippet.  Also, did you try in different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to consider setting the Firefox profile with expected mime type for the content to be download.

> BrowserOption with  Name = "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"
>   Value = "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv,
>   application/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/download,
>   application/octet-stream, binary/octet-stream, application/binary,
>   application/x-unknown"

This worked in my case. When you are manually downloading the file, that time you will need to see for the mime type in developer tools else try using above while creating new Firefox session.